# WARNING: Unable to resolve crossref for figure in quarto html file

Tags: r, quarto

I have a .qmd file with this contents:

```
![](images/plt_pay_bame_diff){#fig-pay_bame_diff}

If you look at @fig-pay_bame_diff
```

It outputs the image, but can't process the crossref to the figure:

[image]

```
metadata
  document-css: false
  link-citations: true
  date-format: long
  lang: en
  
WARNING: Unable to resolve crossref @fig-pay_bame_diff
Output created: test.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not working because you have not provided a figure caption (i.e. `fig-cap`).

For markdown image syntax, figure caption goes within the sqaure brackets `[]`.

So try with,

```
![some label](images/plt_pay_bame_diff){#fig-pay_bame_diff}

If you look at @fig-pay_bame_diff
```

Comment: thanks again Shafee, I was being a bit lazy here, it would be good to have a slightly better error message though. I will try and raise it on github